# How to add an aria attribute to a styled component?

Tags: styled-components

I am using the `styled-components` npm package and need to add the `aria-haspopup` attribute to my extended Button component. I have tried the following, but this doesn't add the attribute:

```
import Button from './button';

const StyledBtn = Button.attrs({
    'aria-haspopup': 'true',
}).extend``;
```

Answer (score 8):

I found that the solution was:

**New styled-components v4 syntax:**

```
import Button from './button';

const StyledBtn = styled(Button).attrs({
    'aria-haspopup': 'true',
})``;
```

**Old syntax:**

```
import Button from './button';

const StyledBtn = Button.extend.attrs({
    'aria-haspopup': 'true',
})``;
```

https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api

https://medium.com/styled-components/styled-components-v4-new-final-finalest-for-real-final-final-psd-fa4d83398a77

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

```
import Button from './button';

const StyledBtn = Button.attrs(({ value }) => ({
  ariaHaspopup: value,
}));
```

Comment: I tested this in styled-components v4, and this is incorrect. It errors with `Button.attrs is not a function`