# React styled: Wrapper component produces `Using kebab-case for css properties in objects is not supported. Did you mean ariaLabel?` error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, accessibility

*Using emotion/styled v11*

#### Background

In order to change the default `type` of all buttons in my project, I wrote a wrapper component `WrappedButton` for the HTML `<button>`.
In order to allow this new `WrappedButton` component to be `styled` (`styled(WrappedButton)({...})`), I needed to wrap my `WrapperButton` with `styled`.

#### Problem

When trying to set the `aria-label` attribute on my `WrappedButton` I get the console error `Using kebab-case for css properties in objects is not supported. Did you mean ariaLabel?`

When I change `aria-label` to `ariaLabel`, there's no error, but then the label is not set.

#### Question

How can I get rid of the error while keeping my use cases intact?

#### Code

**WrappedButton**

```
type ButtonPropsType = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>;
type RefType = ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined;

/** 
  * This is needed in order to allow the button to be styled by
  * emotion (`styled(WrappedButton)({...})`
 **/
const StylableButton = styled.button({}, (props: ButtonPropsType) => ({
    ...(props as any),
}));

// change default `type` from `submit` to `button`
const defaultProps: ButtonPropsType = {
    type: 'button',
};

export const WrappedButton = forwardRef((props: ButtonPropsType, ref: RefType) => {
    return <StylableButton {...defaultProps} ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
WrappedButton.displayName = 'Button';
```

**Usage**

```
test('A', () => {
    render(<WrappedButton aria-label='foo'>a</WrappedButton>);
});
```

### What I've tried:

*shouldForwardProp*

```
const StylableButton = styled('button',
  {
  //shouldForwardProp: (prop) => (prop !== 'aria-label')
  }
)({}, (props: ButtonPropsType) => ({
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => (prop !== 'aria-label'),
    ...(props as any),
}));
```

Comment: Does this help somehow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083705/how-to-add-an-aria-attribute-to-a-styled-component I just tried in the styled components interactive demo and added an aria attribute, there was no error or warning.

Comment: It seems like the `attrs` functionality was removed :(

Comment: Seems to be working on this sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hqzqfk?file=App.tsx

Comment: @vighnesh153 I'm not sure if you're referring to `attrs`, but your solution indeed worked. It seems like `StylableButton` can be defined as `const StylableButton = styled.button()` (testing at the moment) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out from [vighnesh153](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8822610/vighnesh153)'s comment:

The solution is to remove mentioning of `props` from the definition of `StylableButton`:

```
const StylableButton = styled.button();
```

Apparently, everything works as expected already behind the scenes without mentioning the props.

Here's the full source:

```
type ButtonPropsType = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>;
type RefType = ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined;

/** 
  * This is needed in order to allow the button to be styled by
  * emotion (`styled(WrappedButton)({...})`
 **/
const StylableButton = styled.button();

// change default `type` from `submit` to `button`
const defaultProps: ButtonPropsType = {
    type: 'button',
};

export const WrappedButton = forwardRef((props: ButtonPropsType, ref: RefType) => {
    return <StylableButton {...defaultProps} ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
WrappedButton.displayName = 'Button';
```